# Using WSSE plugin for Gsoap in C++/Linux

Tags: c++, linux, ws-security, gsoap

How can we implement WSSE plugin for Gsoap in C++/Linux ? 
This [link](http://www.genivia.com/doc/wsse/html/wsse.html) doesn't give all the information.

The problem is what do I have to include in my header file generated by WSDL , to  make it wsse compatible so that soapcpp2  header.h generates sufficient code so that I can compile wsseapi.c successfully ?

Also ,if possible please provide working sample code(C++ only , no C plz) which implements wsse plugin?

Answer (score 5):

To automatically add an `#import "wsse.h"` to the wsdl2h-generated header file if it is not already there (wsdl2h detects WS-Security requirements with WS-Policy), then first modify `typemap.dat` to include these three lines:

```
[
#import "wsse.h"
]
```

Then (assuming C++):

1. run `wsdl2h -Iimport -o service.h <your-wsdls-xsds-etc>` and make sure wsdl2h uses the modified `typemap.dat` (if it is in the current dir you are OK) and the import option points to the gsoap `import` directory with `wsse.h`
2. run `soapcpp2 service.h`
3. compile the generated `soapC.cpp`, `soapClient.cpp` (if client), `soapServer.cpp` (if server), `stdsoap2.cpp`, `dom.cpp`, `plugin/wsseapi.c`, `plugin/smdevp.c`, `plugin/mecevp.c`
4. when compiling the above, you must use `-DWITH_OPENSSL` `-DWITH_DOM`
5. link against `-lssl` and `-lcrypto`
6. to enable HTTP compression, compile with `-DWITH_GZIP` and link with `-lz`

When compiling in C, do all of the above but use wsdl2h option `-c` and use the .c files.

See the [WSSE documentation](http://www.genivia.com/doc/wsse/html/wsse.html) and also the `gsoap/samples/wssedemo` example in the gsoap package, which shows the API calls to use WS-Security in several possible ways, tells you how to register the plugin etc.

Answer (score -1):

> what do I have to include in my header file

```
#import "wsse.h"
```

(See comments in the header file, or the generated documentation for part starting "*Policy Enablers of Binding*")

Update: 
Copy & Paste from generated documentation:

```
WS-Security (SOAP Message Security) 1.0 (accepts 1.1):

#import "wsse.h" // to be added to this header file for the soapcpp2 build step
#include "plugin/wsseapi.h"
soap_register_plugin(soap, soap_wsse); // register the wsse plugin in your code
// See the user guide gsoap/doc/wsse/html/index.html
```

(this can be found in generated doxygen documentation for your bindings)

See also [how-to section](http://www.genivia.com/doc/wsse/html/wsse.html).